# MySQLの行列変換で複数条件指定

Tags: mysql, sql

1日に4時限あり，複数クラスの割当表を作成しています。
最低1時限から受講者は参加し，最大4時限で，どの組にも参加できます。
もちろん参加しないで空くこともあります。

DBには左側のようにレコードが保存されていて，それを行列変換したいのですが，行き詰っています。

どうぞよろしくお願いします。

[image: 左がDB格納状態のテーブル。右側が出力させたい形式]

Comment: 通常のSQLでデータを取得した後、アプリケーション側で加工したほうが良い要件のように思われます。プログラムはどの言語で実装するのでしょうか？

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。PHPを想定しています。

Comment: テーブル表示にする場合，構造が複雑になるため，行列変換で1回で取得できればと考えました。

Answer (score 7, accepted):

一般的にこう言う操作はピボット(PIVOT)と言いますので、そういうキーワードで調べれば答えが見つかります。SQLでなくてもflattenとかflatMapとか、よくある操作です。

ご希望の結果とは若干違うかもしれませんがMySQLであればGROUP_CONCATを使うと、SELECTしてきた文字列をカンマ区切りの文字列に変換できます。SEPARATORを指定すればカンマ以外の文字を指定することもできます。

組をcls,名前をname,時限をperiodとして、テーブルを作成して、実験した結果です。

```
create table t1 (
  cls varchar(1),
  name varchar(1),
  period varchar(1)
);
```

このテーブルにデータを入れて

```
insert into t1 values(1,'a',1), (1,'b',1), (2,'c',1), (2,'d',1), (3,'e',1), (3,'f',1), (4,'g',1), (4,'h',1), (1,'a',2), (1,'c',2), (2,'i',2), (2,'j',2), (3,'k',2), (3,'l',2), (4,'m',2), (4,'b',2), (1,'n',3), (1,'o',3), (2,'p',3), (2,'q',3), (3,'r',3), (3,'s',3), (4,'t',3), (4,'u',3), (1,'v',4), (1,'w',4), (2,'x',4), (2,'a',4), (3,'f',4), (3,'h',4), (4,'y',4), (4,'z',4);
```

SELECTを実行します。

```
select cls,
       group_concat(case when period=1 then name end order by 1) as period1,
       group_concat(case when period=2 then name end order by 1) as period2,
       group_concat(case when period=3 then name end order by 1) as period3,
       group_concat(case when period=4 then name end order by 1) as period4
from t1
group by cls
order by cls
```

結果

```
cls      period1    period2    period3    period4
1        a,b        a,c        n,o        v,w
2        c,d        i,j        p,q        a,x
3        e,f        k,l        r,s        f,h
4        g,h        b,m        t,u        y,z
```

追記：受講者の名前のソートを追加しました。

Comment: GROUP_CONCATの文字列の長さはデフォルトで1024byteまで。group_concat_max_len で変えられる。

Answer (score 0):

名前の並びに指定がなかったので、ひとまずアルファベット順に並べて作ってみました。
名前の並びに自由度をもたせるには、順序を格納する列を追加してください。

```
CREATE TABLE `参加表` (
  `組` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `名前` varchar(256) NOT NULL,
  `時限` int(11) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO `参加表` (`組`, `名前`, `時限`)
VALUES (1, 'Aさん', 1)
, (1, 'Bさん', 1)
, (2, 'Cさん', 1)
, (2, 'Dさん', 1)
, (3, 'Eさん', 1)
, (3, 'Fさん', 1)
, (4, 'Gさん', 1)
, (4, 'Hさん', 1)
, (1, 'Aさん', 2)
, (1, 'Cさん', 2)
, (2, 'Iさん', 2)
, (2, 'Jさん', 2)
, (3, 'Kさん', 2)
, (3, 'Lさん', 2)
, (4, 'Mさん', 2)
, (4, 'Bさん', 2)
, (1, 'Nさん', 3)
, (1, 'Oさん', 3)
, (2, 'Pさん', 3)
, (2, 'Qさん', 3)
, (3, 'Rさん', 3)
, (3, 'Sさん', 3)
, (4, 'Tさん', 3)
, (4, 'Uさん', 3)
, (1, 'Vさん', 4)
, (1, 'Wさん', 4)
, (2, 'Xさん', 4)
, (2, 'Aさん', 4)
, (3, 'Fさん', 4)
, (3, 'Hさん', 4)
, (4, 'Yさん', 4)
, (4, 'Zさん', 4);
```

たとえば、4組を取得するには下記のSQLを実行します。([実行結果](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5d47b/1/5))
全部の組を取得するには `UNION ALL` で結合するか、PHP側でループを回して組み立ててください。

```
SET @rownum = 0;
SET @rownum1 = 0;
SET @rownum2 = 0;
SET @rownum3 = 0;
SET @rownum4 = 0;
SELECT rownum_base.`組` "組"
, period1.`名前` "1時限"
, period2.`名前` "2時限"
, period3.`名前` "3時限"
, period4.`名前` "4時限"
FROM
( SELECT @rownum := @rownum + 1 rownum
  , `組`
  FROM `参加表`
  WHERE `組` = 4
  ORDER BY `名前`
) rownum_base
  LEFT JOIN
( SELECT @rownum1 := @rownum1 + 1 rownum
  , `参加表`.*
  FROM `参加表`
  WHERE `組` = 4
    AND `時限` = 1
  ORDER BY `名前`
) period1
  ON period1.rownum = rownum_base.rownum
  LEFT JOIN
( SELECT @rownum2 := @rownum2 + 1 rownum
  , `参加表`.*
  FROM `参加表`
  WHERE `組` = 4
    AND `時限` = 2
  ORDER BY `名前`
) period2
  ON period2.rownum = rownum_base.rownum
  LEFT JOIN
( SELECT @rownum3 := @rownum3 + 1 rownum
  , `参加表`.*
  FROM `参加表`
  WHERE `組` = 4
    AND `時限` = 3
  ORDER BY `名前`
) period3
  ON period3.rownum = rownum_base.rownum
  LEFT JOIN
( SELECT @rownum4 := @rownum4 + 1 rownum
  , `参加表`.*
  FROM `参加表`
  WHERE `組` = 4
    AND `時限` = 4
  ORDER BY `名前`
) period4
  ON period4.rownum = rownum_base.rownum
WHERE
  COALESCE(period1.rownum, period2.rownum
, period3.rownum, period4.rownum) IS NOT NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

ついでです。SQL のみで実現するとするとこうなります。([実行結果](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5d47b/8/0))

rownum_base で枠を作り、時限単位に並べた四つの表を結合します。

```
SELECT rownum_base.`組` "組"
, period1.`名前` "1時限"
, period2.`名前` "2時限"
, period3.`名前` "3時限"
, period4.`名前` "4時限"
FROM
( SELECT DISTINCT
  ( SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `参加表` 
    WHERE `名前` <= A.`名前` AND `組` = A.`組` AND `時限` = A.`時限`
  ) rownum
  , `組`
  FROM `参加表` A
) rownum_base
  LEFT JOIN
( SELECT
  ( SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `参加表`
    WHERE `名前` <= P1.`名前` AND `組` = P1.`組` AND `時限` = P1.`時限`
  ) rownum
 , P1.*
  FROM `参加表` P1
  WHERE `時限` = 1
) period1
  ON period1.rownum = rownum_base.rownum
    AND period1.`組` = rownum_base.`組`
  LEFT JOIN
( SELECT
  ( SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `参加表`
    WHERE `名前` <= P2.`名前` AND `組` = P2.`組` AND `時限` = P2.`時限`
  ) rownum
  , P2.*
  FROM `参加表` P2
  WHERE `時限` = 2
) period2
  ON period2.rownum = rownum_base.rownum
    AND period2.`組` = rownum_base.`組`
  LEFT JOIN
( SELECT
  ( SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `参加表`
    WHERE `名前` <= P3.`名前` AND `組` = P3.`組` AND `時限` = P3.`時限`
  ) rownum
  , P3.*
  FROM `参加表` P3
  WHERE `時限` = 3
) period3
  ON period3.rownum = rownum_base.rownum
    AND period3.`組` = rownum_base.`組`
  LEFT JOIN
( SELECT
  ( SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `参加表`
    WHERE `名前` <= P4.`名前` AND `組` = P4.`組` AND `時限` = P4.`時限`
  ) rownum
  , P4.*
  FROM `参加表` P4
  WHERE `時限` = 4
) period4
  ON period4.rownum = rownum_base.rownum
    AND period4.`組` = rownum_base.`組`
WHERE
  COALESCE(period1.rownum, period2.rownum
, period3.rownum, period4.rownum) IS NOT NULL;
```

Answer (score -1):

例示のテーブルを単純に行列変換だけしました。
時限ごとにぶった切った4つの副問い合わせ結果から組と名前を拾い上げる感じ。

※もとのテーブルをbasetblとしています
※正しく動作するか試していません。何も考えずゴリゴリ書いただけです
※「参加しないで空くこともある」の条件を無視しています

```
select distinct
c.組,
j1.名前 AS '1時限',
j2.名前 AS '2時限',
j3.名前 AS '3時限',
j4.名前 AS '4時限'
from
( select distinct 組 from basetbl) c,
( select 組,名前 from basetbl where 時限 = '1時限') j1,
( select 組,名前 from basetbl where 時限 = '2時限') j2,
( select 組,名前 from basetbl where 時限 = '3時限') j3,
( select 組,名前 from basetbl where 時限 = '4時限') j4
where
c.組=j1.組,
c.組=j2.組,
c.組=j3.組,
c.組=j4.組
order by
c.組
```

SQL1文で全てをやろうとすると性能が犠牲になるので
select * で全て抽出し、プログラム内で加工するか
軸を決めて(上記の場合は時限)、軸ごとのviewを作り、そこから抽出したほうが良いです。

上記のSQLもデータ件数が増えるとまず返って来ないでしょうね

Comment: あるクラスある時限に複数のレコードがあるので、その組み合わせがそのまま列挙されて (1組,A,A,N,V),(1組,A,A,N,W),(1組,A,A,O,V),(1組,A,A,O,W),... という結果になってしまいますね

Comment: where句の条件を下記に変更してみて下さい。c.組=j1.組, j1.組=j2.組, j2.組=j3.組, j3.組=j4.組　全く試さずに回答してすみません。